# Query MST instead of UTC for timestamps

Tags: sql-server, timestamp, utc-time

on SQL Server, i'm trying to query all of last months data based off of the time stamp, however, all those timestamps are in UTC and i need them to be in MST (the reason is mainly for the end dates)

So far this is what I have:

```
Select Vehicle.Timestamp
WHERE Vehicle.Timestamp >= DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,32,GETUTCDATE()),0) 
AND Vehicle.Timestamp < DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETUTCDATE()),0) 
order by Vehicle.Timestamp
```

i'm not entirely sure which way to move forward.

I've seen the use of `switchoffset` however, not sure the best way to apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need this for a one-time query, I'd recommend something like this:

```
WITH AdjustedVehicleInfo AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, -7, Timestamp) AS MST_Timestamp 
    FROM Vehicle
)
SELECT MST_Timestamp
FROM AdjustedVehicleInfo
WHERE MST_Timestamp BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

where `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` are set to MST times.

The reason I put that disclaimer is because the offset between `GETDATE()` and `GETUTCDATE()` is not always -7 for MST, and indeed is not the same across all timeframes for most timezones (places like Arizona and other non-DST-observant localities being exceptions). If you want this to become a query that people/software is going to use for a long time, you'll need to figure out a different way of adjusting the values to the desired timezone.

Comment: Yeah i was able to figure this solution out. It'll do for now! Thanks